# How to achieve positional servo control with an Atmega328P?

Tags: atmega, servo, atmega328p

I am trying to drive my SG90 servo using the timers on the Atmega329P using phase correct PWM. I have set up my motor well enough that it rotates, but I cannot get it to stop - the servo motor just continues rotating.

Here's my current code:
`servo.c`

```
#define F_CPU 16000000L

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "servocontrol.h"

#define TOP 500 // 1000*(64/16000000)

void servo_delay() {
   _delay_ms(1500);

}


void setup_servos() {
   DDRD = (1 << DDD5) | (1 << DDD6);
   TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0A1) | (1 << COM0A0) | (1 << WGM00) | (1 << COM0B1);
   TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01);
   OCR0A = 0x00;

}

void move_servos() {
   for (int i = 100; i < TOP; i++) {
      OCR0A = i;
      servo_delay();
      if (OCR0A == 300) {
          PORTD &= ~ (1 << PD5);
        }

    }
}
```

`servocontrol.h`

```
#ifndef SERVOCONTROL_H
#define SERVOCONTROL_H

void servo_delay();

void setup_servos();

void move_servos();

#endif
```

`main.c`

```
#define F_CPU 16000000L

#include <avr/io.h>
#include "servocontrol.h"

int main() {
    setup_servos();
    move_servos();
}
```

I'm trying to use `timer0` in phase correct non-inverting mode, but I exprecienced the same problem when I used `timer1`.
How do I get the servo to stop at the location I want? I feel like there is a part of the PWM process that I am currently missing, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I will greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: First, you use the `edit` button post the code you are *actually using* and not a fraction of it missing the linkage between procedures.  Next, you realize that your code appears to be continuously changing the commanded position, and that if you want the hobby servo motor to stop, you need to stop doing that and instead command a steady position.

Comment: I've edited my post with the header file and `main` function. That's all the code I'm using. 
How do I command a steady position? I have tried with a statement like `OCR0A = 200` in the `move_servo()` function, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Well, you seem personally offended with how I'm phrasing my questions. I'm sorry that my questions do not apparently meet your expectations, but since you have neither helped me with my problem or actually told me how I could improve my questions, you could also have just ignored my post altogether. I will *definitely* try harder next time when I'm posting my questions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: -1 the posted code obviously cannot accomplish the desired goal, **as it commands the servo to move to varying positions, not achieve a fixed one**.  If you have code that is written with a reasonable attempt at holding a fixed position as you desire, that can be considered on its merits if and when posted.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 1.5s delay is more then enough to see servo get to position and _hold_ it. Besides, OP mentioned setting OCR0A to _constant_ 200 value, which is exactly a "reasonable attempt at holding a fixed position". -1 is totally undeserved.

Comment: @Maple - the point is that code in the question does not represent the asker's viable attempt to solve the problem.  If they tried a constant, then that - not the obviously inappropriate `for` loop, is what they needed to post.  And the reason for that is that there might be *other* errors they aren't telling us about.  This kind of consistency of what you show with what you ask is a fundamental principle of the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: Once again: the "for" loop with suitable delay is totally appropriate if you want to see servo following your commands. The only mistake OP made is the use of wrong divider value. I thought helping people find mistakes like that is what Stack Exchange is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 16 Mhz and with 1/64 clock source you have 250 kHz TC frequency. You set TOP to FF (WGM00), so your PWM period is 2 ms. Normal hobby servos need period about 20 ms (50 Hz).

You can try 1/1024 clock for 32 ms period (at TOP = FF). Then OCR0A between 8 and 16 will give you 1 to 2 ms pulse width, for 8 positions of servo resolution.

You can use Fast PWM mode for 16 ms period. Then OCR0A between 16 and 32 will give you same 1 to 2 ms pulse width, for 16 positions of servo resolution.

Or you can use Timer1 with OCR1A as TOP for precise period control and OCR1B as duty cycle with much better resolution.

Comment: Thank you, Maple, for your help. It lead me on the right path. My resolution was the problem.